# VS Code congela ao interromper execução no terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

Estou tentando usar o VS Code pelas facilidades das extensões, principalmente pelos destaques de cor. Também para fazer uso do debugador.

O problema é que ao rodar a aplicação, seja com o C++ Compile/Run, ou com o Code Runner, ele começa a executar o código (já no terminal), e quando clico no botão de interromper a execução, o programa completo congela.

Obs: o atalho nativo do code runner (Ctrl + Alt + M) para interromper a execução também não funciona.

Tenho o MinGW instalado e adicionado ao PATH, uso Windows 10 64-bit.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Gustavo! Seja bem-vindo. Me perdoe a curiosidade mas é para trabalhos escolares esse ambiente ou para uso profissional no dia a dia?

Comment: Uma pergunta: Por quê você não experimenta usar o CLion da JetBrains? É grátis para estudantes. Por isso perguntei se vc estava usando o VSCode na condição de aluno ou na empresa. Caso queira baixar o CLion e experimentar: https://www.jetbrains.com/community/education/#students

Comment: Sem as extensões funciona normalmente? está usando o ubuntu for windows, bash, ou o próprio cmd? não entendo muito bem de Windows, mas talvez usando 'outro tipo' de terminal, solucione o problema..

Comment: Obrogado, Mateus! É para estudo, n faço faculdade de computação, faço Física, mas está trancada no momento, então nem conseguiria a licença gratuita, sabe? Mas uso por interesse msm, tenho vontade de desenvolver jogos. Já vinha programando no Dev C++, mas almejei as ferramentas e possibilidades do VS... enfim, obrigado!

Comment: Gleidson, sem todas as extensões ele à princípio não compila. Ele me leva pro launch.json, destacando a seguinte linha: "console": "externalTerminal".

Só com o Code Runner ele diz "Property Console Not Allowed" e me leva pra mesma linha do launch.json. Isso tudo é com a execução habilitada no terminal.

Se desabilito essa opção, ele executa o programa pela aba "saída", e portanto não consigo dar input.

Comment: Agradeceria se soubesse me orientar a executar em terminal externo, como no cmd do windows! Acho que resolveria o problema.